# How insert an existing EC2 instance as container host in docker-machine?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-machine

Using docker-machine in Windows 10 OS, I would like to insert an existing EC2 instance as containers host, and use this for host containers and networks created by docker-composer, but I did not find any tutorial or a full explaination about it, Therefore I have the following questions.

1. Is it necessary install docker and run docker deamon on EC2 instance
   first?
2. Should I config 2376 port as inbound of my EC2 instance secury group
3. Which driver should I use in command `docker-machine create`, none
       or generic?
4. How deal with authentication, using the pem file generated at the
   EC2 instance initialization, or using IAM user credentials, How I
   do it?
5. Using docker-composer for create containers and networks, It's
   needed any addtional configuration on EC2 instance?

Examples and tutorials for reference, are highly valued for me.

Comment: If you haven't seen the GitHub issue on the subject yet, check out https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3212. Though, it mostly sounds unresolved and there isn't a very simple way to do it.

Comment: this issue could't anwer all my questions